# Updating OpenZFS to latest version

Tags: zfs

I have a fresh system running Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS and I installed ZFS from the repositories using:

`apt install zfsutils-linux`

This installed v2.2.0 and I'd like to update ZFS to the latest version 2.2.2. What is the best method to update?

```
$ sudo dmesg | grep ZFS
[ 3794.221856] ZFS: Loaded module v2.2.0-0ubuntu1~23.10, ZFS pool version 5000, ZFS filesystem version 5
$ zfs --version
zfs-2.1.5-1ubuntu6~22.04.2
zfs-kmod-2.2.0-0ubuntu1~23.10
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software)

Comment: You need to upgrade to a new Ubuntu release to get 2.2.2. https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=zfsutils-linux says only Ubuntu 24.04 will have it, so you need to wait a few months and upgrade. Or you could look for a PPA

Comment: Yes that helps but I'm interested in understanding the update process. I wanted to update to v2.2.2 manually to get familiar.

Comment: "manually" is only likely to break your system. Even if apt lets you (or if you force it) and your system still boots after installing the .deb downloaded from https://packages.ubuntu.com/noble/zfsutils-linux , it will likely not run. You will probably see LIBC errors while trying to run any commands from a package from a newer Ubuntu version.

Comment: Agree - you should stick to the standard Ubuntu ZFS version. Yes you can compile your own newer kernel module, but in this case please know what you're doing.